# Java thread group and thread local

Tags: java, multithreading

I am storing some data thread local first and then starting multiple threads using below code.

```
CompletionService<> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(managedExecutorService);
```

I want to access the above thread local stored data in running child threads (threads those are ran by `ExecutorService`).

However, when I try to access it, its throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That's because ThreadLocal data, by its very definition, is data which is local to a thread. Your executor starts **different** threads, so they don't have access to the data that is local to your main thread. Note that, instead of describing your code, you should **post it**. This looks like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you use a ThreadLocal to share information between threads?

Comment: Each thread needs to use some data from external systems, so if I have a 20 threads then I have to call that external system 20 time which is the decreasing the performance. In stead of this I want to  call it once for all 20 threads (as the external service accepts list of request parameters) and while running each thread I will resolve this data specific to each thread. I can store it in a cache and read it from there, but I am looking for a solution if I can do it inside thread.

Comment: Storing it in a cache and accessing it in your threads seems fine. Why do you want to change it? ThreadLocal is certainly not the right place to store it. It’s usually used by threads that run the same code but might be operating on a `different` piece of some data. Even then there other ways to do it.

Comment: You are correct even the target plan is to read it from cache. As threads are generated from threadgroup/executor service, look like parent-child model of processing the task. Then there should be some mechanism to read parent data.